# Document Upload Custom Browse Button

Tags: javascript, file-upload, document-upload

I am trying to customize the "Browse/Choose File" button on a document upload. I am using SharePoint 2016 on-prem, classic.[image: image of document upload]

So when a user clicks the button to select the file from their computer the windows explorer opens to a specific folder on their desktop. Every users desktop in our organization has this folder where they store weekly reports.

So for example: when a user clicks Choose File it will open directly to the Cluster_Logs folder on their desktop.[image]

Is there a way to override that with JavaScript so I can force where the window opens to?

Comment: Don't forget to include which version of SharePoint you are on and whether on-prem or online, and modern versus classic sites.  When needing UI customizations the answer can very different depending on these factors.

Comment: Thank you, good point. I added that info.

Answer (score 0):

Due to browser security, no this isn't possible.

While not marked as an answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14119707 which is correct for this question.

Comment: That's what I figured, thank you for your answer!